# pdb enter repeats last command of alias not the alias itself

Tags: python-3.x, pdb

I defined an alias in .pdbrc file as:

```
# Next and list, and step and list.
alias nl n;;l
alias sl s;;l
```

This works fine. But say when I press enter after `nl` it runs the last command of the alias which is `l` in this case. But I would rather have it run the alias instead. Is there a way to achieve this?